# Trigger event when scrolling div into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to register an event when the user scrolls to the top and bottom of the page, but can't get an event to trigger when the user scrolls below the fold of the page. I have a div in the middle `#below-fold`, that I need to trigger when it comes into the viewport of the browser on scrolling down.

I need to do this **WITHOUT** an additional plugin.

HTML

```
<div class="top">TOP</div>
<div id="below-fold">Fold</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
var $win = $(window);

$win.scroll(function () {
    if ($win.scrollTop() == 0) {
        console.log("USER SCROLLED TO TOP");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled To Top", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() >= $('#below-fold').height() - 0 && $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() <= $('#below-fold').height() + 0) {
        console.log("VIEWED BELOW THE FOLD");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled Below Fold", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    } else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
        console.log("USER SCROLLED TO BOTTOM");
        mixpanel.track(
            "User Scrolled To Bottom", {
            "url": window.location.href
        });
    }
});

});
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/rndam8ns/)

Comment: Are you looking to use the `$.trigger('event');` function? What do you mean by 'that I need to trigger'?

Comment: Think he means just getting output into the console for now

Comment: I need to have mixpanel event/console.log triggered when the user scrolls to the `#below-fold` div.

Comment: So once the `#below-fold` element comes into view?

Comment: @AdamMazzarella - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the else if to:

```
else if ($win.scrollTop() >= $('#below-fold').position().top - $win.height() && $win.height() + $win.scrollTop()  < $(document).height())
```

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/rndam8ns/6/

added `var triggered = false` into the mix, so that it only triggers once on scroll down and when it scrolls to the top, it'll reset and trigger again

Comment: This is good, but I need to only have the event triggered one time when the user scrolls the `below-fold` div into view. With this, it is triggered on every pixel of the div.

Comment: @Matt what if the user scrolls to top and then re-scroll into below-fold view? should the event be fired again?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio - yes, I'd like to have it function that way as well. It just needs to fire one time when it hits the below-fold div. In your demo it fires with every pixel of the div that is brought into view.

Comment: @Matt: updated the code to handle trigger once on scroll down and trigger reset on triggered event of scrolling to the top

Answer (score 0):

You should test [element].offset().top in your IF:

EDIT: To check only the first enter event, you could use a flag like in the example.

```
$(function () {
    var $win = $(window);
    var $fold = $('#below-fold');
    var inTheFold = false;

    $win.scroll(function () {

        console.log($win.scrollTop());
        console.log($fold.offset().top);
        console.log(inTheFold);

        if ($win.scrollTop() >= $fold.offset().top && $win.scrollTop() <= $fold.offset().top+$fold.height() )
        {  
            if (!inTheFold) {
              inTheFold = true;
              console.log("VIEWED BELOW THE FOLD");
              mixpanel.track(
                "User Scrolled Below Fold", {
                "url": window.location.href
              });
            }

        } else if ($win.scrollTop() <= $fold.offset().top || $win.scrollTop() >= $fold.offset().top+$fold.height() ) {

            if (inTheFold) {
                inTheFold = false;
              console.log("EXITED THE FOLD");
              mixpanel.track(
                "EXITED THE FOLD", {
                "url": window.location.href
              });
            }

        }
    });

});
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rndam8ns/7/